# Qt: printing on printer dot matrix

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I'm trying to print some string to a printer dot matrix LX-300+ using Qt but it seems that the font is skewed. Some users also have this problem http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11814-printing-program-in-LX-300-(dot-matrix-printer)-problem but i can't find the solutions until now. Please help me to address this problem. Do i need to create a dll or application using other framework maybe .net if this is Qt bug? Here is my code

```
QTextDocument document;
QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(&document);
QFont font = QFont("Courier");
QTextCharFormat format = QTextCharFormat();
format.setFont(font);
cursor.setCharFormat(format);
cursor.insertText("lorem ipsum dolor sit amit amit ");

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::ScreenResolution);
printer.setPrinterName(ui->ddlPrinter->currentData().toString());
printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::GrayScale);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setFullPage(false);
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
document.print(&printer);
```

i'm using Qt5.4.0 mingw491 32 OS win 7 64bit

Comment: "it seems that the font is skewed" There's no way of even beginning to address your question if you don't provide a legible (**600dpi+ scan**) image of the problem printout. To reproduce, you'll also have to set an explicit font on the `QTextDocument`, and let us know what OS it's on, what Qt version, and what printer driver version and provider you're using.

Comment: I have added more description, how to set font on QTextDocument?

Comment: Set the `defaultFont` **before** adding any other content to the document.

Comment: You should really add images (or just links to imgur if you can't yet attach images directly, someone will usually quickly edit to add the images) of invalid printout from Qt, and expected printout from Wordpad or Notepad. You can probably get good enough images with camera phone, to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem using Windows API directly like this pseudo code

```
OpenPrinter(name,&hPrinter, NULL);
dwJob = StartDocPrinter( hPrinter, 1, (LPBYTE)&DocInfo );
bStatus = StartPagePrinter(hPrinter);
BOOL bStatus = WritePrinter(hPrinter,(LPVOID)buffer,text.length(),&dwBytesWritten);
```

hope this help someone